# numpy loadtxt skip first row

Tags: python, bash, csv, numpy, import-from-csv

I have a small issue when I'm trying to import data from CSV files with numpy's loadtxt function. Here's a sample of the type of data files I have.

Call it 'datafile1.csv':

```
# Comment 1
# Comment 2
x,y,z 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
...
...
# End of File Comment
```

The script that I thought would work for this situation looks like:

```
import numpy as np
FH = np.loadtxt('datafile1.csv',comments='#',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
```

But, I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: x
```

This tells me that the kwarg 'skiprows' is not skipping the header, it's skipping the first row of comments. I could simply make sure that skiprows=3, but the complication is that I have a very large number of files, which don't all necessarily have the same number of commented lines at the top of the file. How can I make sure that when I use loadtxt I'm only getting the actual data in a situation like this?

P.S. - I'm open to bash solutions, too.

Comment: I should also add that I've tried various solutions in python to parse each line for either a comment or a character, but quickly realized nothing of this nature could possibly work because loadtxt is failing at the very beginning.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Skip comment line manually using generator expression:

```
import numpy as np

with open('datafile1.csv') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if not line.startswith('#'))
    FH = np.loadtxt(lines, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create your own custom filter function, such as:

```
def skipper(fname):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        no_comments = (line for line in fin if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'))
        next(no_comments, None) # skip header
        for row in no_comments:
            yield row

a = np.loadtxt(skipper('your_file'), delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def skipper(fname, header=False):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        no_comments = (line for line in fin if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'))
        if header:
            next(no_comments, None) # skip header
        for row in no_comments:
            yield row

a = np.loadtxt(skipper('your_file'), delimiter=',')
```

This is just a little modification of @Jon Clements's answer by adding an optional parameter "header", given that in some cases, the csv file has comment lines (starts with #) but doesn't have the header row.